# What is the benefit of using no-prefetch on nuxt-link?

Tags: nuxt.js

I understand the benefit of using `nuxt-link` over `a` is that it increases responsiveness of my website because of prefetching. Now reading [nuxt-link component page in nuxtjs.org](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link), I see that there is a way to take out the prefetching by using `no-prefetch`.

I have difficulty understanding why you would want to use `nuxt-link` if this is the case? Wouldn't you want to use something else? Why would you still use `nuxt-link`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using an anchor tag, you are not making full use of your SPA. Your page will just fully reload when navigating between links.

`<nuxt-link />` hooks into Vue Router. So when you click on a `nuxt-link`, the page does not reload. Because the client side routing takes place. Which is much faster and probably one of the reasons why you went for a SPA in the first place anyway.

Prefetching is a cherry on top. If you want extra performance, let the prefetching happen. But won't be a big deal if you won't use it.

Comment: Great description. Thank you very much for explanation! Does that mean, then, I should never use Anchor tag any more other than may be going to outside website?

Answer (score 2):

> You don't need to use it, if you don't needed. Simple.

I'm not sure what do you mean about `you want to use something else`.

`nuxt-link` just a wrapper of `router-link`, with some adjustment. So, if you don't need prefetch, `nuxt-link` just `router-link`.

What's the benefit of using `nuxt-link` (`router-link`) instead of just plain `a` tag?

`nuxt-link` has a lot off stuff, for example if you need to generate link with named routes.

Let's imagine if you have generated routes something like this:

```
{
  path: "/users/:userId?/posts/:id?/:slug?",
  component: _33r1e47x,
  name: "users-id-posts-id-slug"
}
```

You just need to write

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'users-id-posts-id-slug', params: { userId, id, slug }}"></nuxt-link>
```

instead of

```
<a :href="`/users/${userId}/posts/${id}/${slug}`"></a>
```

Comment: If I do not know if there is a benefit, I do not know if I need to use it or do not need to use it. I am here to learn what is the benefit to make informed decision. Thank you very much for your answer.